# I cannot reach my "hello world" website using the Azure free trial

Tags: azure, iis

I'm using the free trial in Azure and I want to create a hello world website and then browse the website from another machine.

The things I've done are:

- Created virtual machine (image: Hardened IIS On Windows Server 2016)
- Created test file (index.htm)
- Mapped website to file (port 7777)
- I can see the hello world page using localhost:7777
- Have created inbound rule (for port 7777)

Is there something else I'm missing?

Many thanks,

**Inbound rule**

[image]

Comment: Not directly related but .. is there a reason you are choosing to spin up a vm with IIS versus using an Azure Web App?

Comment: Just a learning exercise

Comment: Are you sure the url you are using is correct?

Comment: I assume so, I'm browsing within the portal to home\virtual machines\mymachine - networking\ and then copying the "public IP" value into a new browser tab.

Comment: local firewall on server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Information provide [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8622323/tim-tharratt) is correct, Windows Firewall.

In the future you can use Port Query tools (like [PortQuery](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310099/description-of-the-portqry-exe-command-line-utility), [TCPing](https://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) or [PsPing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping)) to identify port blocking issues.

Hope this helps.....